# npm run build always returns status code of 0

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

```
require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

const ora = require('ora')
const rm = require('rimraf')
const path = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

const spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'))
      process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

This is my build script which has been generated as part of a project. I want to detect when a build error has occurred and from this code I would assume the process would return a status code of 1. However when I run

`npm run build`

(with code that causes a build error) I always get a return code of 0. How do i detect build errors?

Comment: Let's assume that the build script is called `build.js`. **1)** Is your `build` script defined in _package.json_ something like this: `"build": "node build.js"`, i..e Does node.js invoke the script via your npm script?. **2)** If you run `node ./build.js` directly via your CLI, (and assuming that a build error does occur), if you then run `echo $?` to obtain the exit code does it print `1` to your console?

Comment: @RobC 
1. yes thats correct
2. when I run in CLI and run echo $1 it prints True (i'm in powershell). It should return False on build error

Comment: **1)** So, if the contents of `build.js` contains  `process.exit(1)` only (nothing else!) and you run `node ./build.js` followed by `echo $?` does it return correctly, i.e. does it correctly return `False` ? **2)** If the aforementioned test exits correctly (i.e. `False`) perhaps try replacing `process.exit(1)` in your current `build.js`  with `process.exitCode = 1` instead. See docs for [`process.exit([code])`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) its shows an example _"// This is an example of what *not* to do:"_ that is akin to your current use of `process.exit(1)`

Comment: Thanks @RobC that helped me crack it. For whatever reason webpack doesn't consider errors as errors they are.... warnings. So if i change 
```if (stats.hasErrors()) {```
to
```if (stats.hasErrors() || stats.hasWarnings()) {```
everything now works